# Create a column with time elapsed (in seconds) since first date based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 3 cols:

| User_id | Country | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |

**Objective:** I need to create a fourth column that is time elapsed in seconds based on user and country's first datetime

**For example**

| User_id | Country | Datetime | TimeElapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Germany | 2020-01-01 14:30:04+00:00 | 0 |
| 123 | Germany | 2020-01-01 14:30:10+00:00 | 6 |
| 123 | France | 2020-01-01 16:34:00+00:00 | 0 |
| 444 | Spain | 2020-01-01 18:05:00+00:00 | 0 |

In SQL I would do a `First_Value` `over (partition by User_id, country order by Datetime asc)`
and do a `datediff` in seconds

**Is it more efficient to do it using pandas or numpy for dataframes with over 200K rows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test the code right now, but I would do something like:

```
# ensure datetime type (optional if already right type)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

# get the first value per group:
df['first'] = df.groupby(['User_id', 'Country']).transform.min() # or first() if you want the first row, not earliest time

# calculate the difference
df['TimeElapsed'] = df['Datetime'] - df['first']
```